# appending image url array in for loop then posting to database

Tags: swift, firebase

I am a bit new to swift development and have come across an issue. I have an array of UIImages that I am running a for loop to create a URL and storing using firebase. the images are stored correctly within my firebase storage but I am currently having an issue creating a post that contains the URLS for the given images.

The correct post should contain itemName, itemPrice, username, imageA, and imageB. the way I have it now is it creates 2 post which I understand because it is in the for loop and it will iterate twice for both images, however I am stuck on figuring how I can just create one post with both images after iterating the for loop to store the images.

```
     @IBAction func confirmAction(_ sender: Any) {

    var uploadedImageUrlsArr = [String]()


    for image in imageArr{
        let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("Advertisement_Images_Main").child("\(imageName).png")

        let myImage = image
        guard let uploadData  = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage) else {
            return
        }
        storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            if let imageURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString{
                print (imageURL)
                uploadedImageUrlsArr.append(imageURL)
                let post : [String : AnyObject] = ["item" : self.itemNameTextField.text as AnyObject, "price" : self.itemPriceTextField.text as AnyObject, "username": self.username as AnyObject, "imageA": imageURL as AnyObject]
                self.ref?.child("Items").childByAutoId().setValue(post)

            }



        })
    }

  //  let post : [String : AnyObject] = ["item" : self.itemNameTextField.text as AnyObject, "price" : self.itemPriceTextField.text as AnyObject, "username": self.username as AnyObject, "imageA": imageURL as AnyObject]

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "confirmedSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `storageRef.putData(...` is an asynchronous call , so you need to wait for the response of both the images to make a post with both of them, so I think you can make these changes in your code to achieve the behaviour you want:

```
        if let imageURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString{
              print (imageURL)
              uploadedImageUrlsArr.append(imageURL)
              if uploadedImageUrlsArr.count == 2 { //you can use self.imageArr.count instead of 2 {
                let post : [String : AnyObject] = ["item" : self.itemNameTextField.text as AnyObject, "price" : self.itemPriceTextField.text as AnyObject, "username": self.username as AnyObject, "imageA": uploadedImageUrlsArr[0] as AnyObject, "imageB": uploadedImageUrlsArr[1] as AnyObject]

                self.ref?.child("Items").childByAutoId().setValue(post)
              }
        }
```

Comment: thanks you, my friend helped me what would have taken 2 full days to figure out. Im still trying to grasp asynchronous vs synchronous calls this is great

Comment: @MatthewDizon no worries, glad I could help, yes asynchronous vs synchronous relationship takes some time to understand, keep learning :)